# covering space of $2$-genus surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm trying to build $2:1$ covering space for $2$- genus surface by $3$-genus surface.
I can see that if I take a cut of $3$-genus surface in the middle (along the mid hole) I get $2$ surfaces each one looks like $2$-genus surface which are open in one side so it's clear how to make the projection from these $2$ copies to the $2$-genus surface.
my question is how can I see this process in the polygonal representation of 3-genus surface
( $12$ edges: $a_{1}b_{1}a_{1}^{-1}b_{1}^{-1}......a_{3}b_{3}a_{3}^{-1}b_{3}^{-1})$ 
. I can't visualize the cut I make in the polygon. 
thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take the dodecagon at the origin with one pair of edges intersecting the $y$-axis (call them the top and bottom faces) and one pair intersecting the $x$-axis. Cut the polygon along the $x$ axis, and **un**-identify the left and right faces. This gives two octagons, each with an opposing pair of unmatched edges. Identify these new edges, and you should have what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see how I get two 2-genus surfaces, can you add a script maybe?

Comment: Actually, I was just undoing the following operation: take two octagons that are genus-2 surfaces, uncouple a pair of edges from each (i.e. unidentify a pair of edges of each) and then glue the two octagons together along two of the new edges. Then identify the last two edges. This gives a 14-gon, but looking at the labels, you can reduce the edges to 12. I want to add a picture, but I'm on the iPad.

Comment: I understood. thanks you

Comment: @BrianRushton could you explain how to reduce the edges to 12? I'm missing something with my labels.